“Matrix” weighted average
Let $U,V,W$ be finite dimensional real vector spaces. Let $A: U \rightarrow W$ and $B: V \rightarrow W$ be linear maps. For a pair of vectors $x,y \in W$, consider the quantity:
$$F(x,y) = (BB^*)(A A^* + B B^*)^{-1}x + (AA^*) (AA^* + BB^*)^{-1}y$$
This is something like a weighted mean of $x$ and $y$, where the weights reflect information about the maps $A$ and $B$. Some support for this interpretation is that if we assume that $A = B$, then we recover the original mean $F(x,y) = \frac{x + y}{2}$. Further if $W = \mathbb{R}$, then $F(x,y) = \frac{||B||^2_F}{||A||^2_F + ||B||^2_F}x + \frac{||A||^2_F}{||A||^2_F + ||B||^2_F}y$, where $||-||_F$ is the Frobenius norm.
I have a few questions about this quantity:

Does this quantity have a nice interpretation in the general case of $A$ and $B$?
This quantity only actually makes sense when $(AA^* + BB^*)$ is invertible, which I believe happens exactly when the block matrix $[A,  B]$ has linearly independent rows. Is there an analogous quantity when this inverse doesn’t exist? I thought about sticking a Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse in, but we no longer recover the usual mean when $A=B$, so I think a different quantity is needed.

(NOTE: I am tagging this with “graph laplacian” because the graph laplacian is very closely related to the reason I’m investigating this quantity.)

Could you elaborate on the relation to the graph laplacian? Are the $AA^$ and $BB^$ discretisations of differential operators on the graph?

A helpful fact: if either $A$ or $B$ is invertible, then $AA^$ or $BB^$ is positive definite, which implies $AA^+BB^$ is also invertible.

@lightxbulb Technically I’m looking at a sheaf laplacian in the style of Hansen and Ghrist. For a two-vertex-one-edge network with restriction maps $A$ and $B$, this quantity is the the edge-stalk value of the nearest global section to our initial points $x$ and $y$.

If you assume that $AA^*$ and $BB^*$ have the same eigenvectors $V$ then you can write $AA^* = VD_AV^*$ and $BB^*=VD_BV^*$. Plugging this into the expression yields:
\begin{align}
F(x,y) &= (BB^*)(AA^*+BB^*)^{-1}x + (AA^*)(AA^*+BB^*)^{-1}y 
\\
&= VD_B(D_A+D_B)^{-1}\underbrace{V^*x}_{z} + VD_A(D_A + D_B)^{-1} \underbrace{V^*y}_w\\
&=
V\left(\frac{D_B}{D_A+D_B}z + \frac{D_A}{D_A+D_B}w\right).
\end{align}
So in this case it is still a weighted average, but in the transformed domain.
Note that $D_{A}\geq 0$ and $D_B\geq 0$ since the matrices $AA^*$ and $BB^*$ are Hermitian positive semi-definite, and the weights sum up to one in each coordinate so you have a convex linear combination.
The above is not invertible when for some $i$ you have $(D_A)_{ii} + (D_B)_{ii} = 0$, which due to the positive semi-definiteness means that $(D_A)_{ii}=(D_{B})_{ii}=0$. But then it probably makes sense to treat $$\frac{(D_A)_{ii}}{(D_{A})_{ii}+(D_B)_{ii}} = \frac{(D_B)_{ii}}{(D_{A})_{ii}+(D_B)_{ii}} :=  0.$$

Hmmm simultaneous diagonalizability is likely too much to ask for my purposes, but this is an interesting observation. Thank you for the suggestion!
